# How do I use JsonConverter with a list?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a `Table`

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ToTableJsonConverter))]
class MyTable : Table
{}
```

```
internal class ToTableJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var tables = (List<Table.Table>)value;
        var array = tables.ToArray();
        writer.WriteValue(array);
    }

}
```

I have a message class which looks like this:

```
class Message
{
    public List<Table.Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

Error message:

> Unsupported type: `PokerServer.Table.TablePineapple`. Use the `JsonSerializer` class to get the object's JSON representation. Path 'Tables.$values'.

I can see the error message but I have no idea that to do. The ultimate goal is to use the `JsonConverter` to only send the necessary properties without having to set all the properties.

**EDIT**:
Also, I have a ContractResolver that needs to retrieve all properties so I need a solution that doesn't stop my ContractResolver from working.

Comment: Read the error message again - nothing to do with lists (this can be trivially shown by serializing a `List<String>`)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to send only certain properties, you should do this using the `[DataContract]`, `[DataMember]`, and `[IgnoreDataMember]` attributes.

```
[DataContract]
class MyObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "x")]
    public string X { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "y")]
    public int Y { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Now calling `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on a `List<MyObject>` will give you something that looks like this:

```
[
    { "x": "apple", "y": 5 },
    { "x": "banana", "y": 8 }
]
```

Note you'll need to reference the `System.Runtime.Serialization` assembly and namespace.

Comment: How could I mix this with a ContractResolver that needs to retreive all properties (when I'm doing a backup to JSON files)?

Comment: @user2524586 In some situations you want to serialize all the values, and in other situations you want to serialize only some?

Comment: That is correct. I have a table with food types etc. that are sent out to the client (a mobile application) and in this stage I want to send as little as possible but when I do a JSON backup I want to save and serialize all properties and fields (which my ContractResolver do now).

Comment: @user2524586 I would do that by using what I've shown in my answer, but creating two model classes: one for backup and one for clients.  ContractResolver is very heavyweight customization for something so simple.